# Multiple Indexes with Apache Solr

Tags: search

Is it possible to use multiple indexes with Apache Solr? We want to use different indexes depending on the environment id.

Answer (score 1):

Setup multiple solr core's and then use settings.php to define for each environment as poster above said.

If you are using ApacheSolr its like:

```
$conf['apachesolr_environments']['my_env_id']['url'] = 'http://localhost:8983';
```

Just make sure your settings.php is not moved from server to server, if it is then use environment variable in apache:

```
SetEnv ENVIRONMENT development
SetEnv ENVIRONMENT staging
SetEnv ENVIRONMENT production
```

And use something like this in settings.php

```
<?php   
switch ($_SERVER['ENVIRONMENT']) { 
  case 'development': 
    $conf['apachesolr_environments']['my_env_id']['url'] = 'http://localhost:8983';
    break;
  case 'production': 
    $conf['apachesolr_environments']['my_env_id']['url'] = 'http://www.domain.com:8983';
    break;
}   
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. One way to do this [on a single Solr server] use Multi-core Solr, and have an index for each environment (Dev, Staging/Test, Prod/Live).

You'll probably want to customize the index file per environment based through some flag you'd set in `settings.php` (per environment); there are utility modules that help split settings amongst each env.